# Deploy static assets to a shared nginx instance

Tags: docker, nginx, deployment

I have an `nginx` serving several static files. It is running as docker container, with the static assets in a docker volume. This works fine, but has a couple of problems:

- the static assets need to be released to the `webserver` project, and deployed from there. This makes the `webserver` project very heavy (contains all websites)
- since the webserver is the one tracking the changes, it needs to be redeployed each time any of the sites changes.
- redeploying any site is thus a multi-step process: build the site, release to the webserver, deploy the webserver (including building the volume with the static assets)

I want to improve on this process. My idea is to follow this process for each site that I want to serve with nginx:

- build the static assets when building a docker image
- use a helper container to copy the static assets from the docker image to the volume mounted in the webserver container

This way, releasing of each site happens independently. If I understand this correctly, since only the static assets are changing (the nginx config remains unchanged nginx does not even need to be restarted: it will automatically pick the new, updated assets.

Is there a better approach than this one? Could you provide some comments / links on how to improve on this strategy?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your existing setup. What is the relationship between `nginx` and `webserver` at runtime? The `webserver` project is different than `nginx`? Where are the static assets currently built/generated in your process?

Comment: @bluescores the webserver project is the one deploying the nginx instance. Currently it gets a copy of the static assets that will be served by nginx. That is, whenever any project with static assets needs to be released, I copy those static assets to the webserver project, and redeploy the webserver project, so that the new assets are active in the production environment.